# Poll instruments to find out if last used for measuring, testing, or calibration

Tags: python-3.x, pyvisa

I'm using LAN connection where I have the instrument set up my goal is to store information on all equipment like a log of when it was calibrated, when it was last used for measuring or testing.

I've tried finding information regarding this on the equipment manual and VISA documentation. I guess mainly I'm trying to find out if this is possible and if so some information on where I can start looking

The expected use case:

I have all instruments connected to same LAN network.
I use computer to find information on every equipment at once and store that information in a CSV file and their status(last used for measuring, testing, calibrated) and create a log of each equipment based on this. This way I can identify what instrument is being used a lot and which one isn't.

Thanks

Comment: Well, that's not a question of VISA but whether or not the device stores such information and if yes, if it is accessible using VISA, right?

Comment: Yes the solution I ended up going with is trying a lot of queries to pin point instrument type and then querying even more types of data acquisition methods in order to find out if it is doing anything that way I can reliably say its being used or if it is online but not being used or offline. Its not the cleanest way I reckon there is probably a better solution out there but I have currently settled on this till I can find something better.

Comment: OK, wouldn't work if it is used offline, though. If they only can be used online, a device server might be a solution.

Comment: Currently every device detected gets their VISA address added to database so I can retrieve them and ping to see if online or not before moving forward.